# Link is redirecting in local host instead of actual website

Tags: php, sql, html

I have a table with different column. on of them is website, which should redirect me to a website when clicked upon. however it is looking the website up in my local host.

> http://127.0.0.1:8090/test/http://www.amity.edu/mauritius/

it should be

> http://www.amity.edu/mauritius/

here is the code for the table:

```
<?php


include ('db_connect.php');

$sql="select * from institution";



$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ins_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ins_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=" . $row['website'] . ">" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
?>
```

What should i do to make it go to the website?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend your URL with `http://` or `https://`

```
echo "<td><a href='http://" . $row['website'] . "'>" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this, use single quotes for href, and use protocol

```
$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';
echo "<td><a href='" $protocol. $row['website'] . "'>" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: It is still looking it up on my local host.

Comment: as rakesh said check into database table for column `website` ? what value you have ?

Comment: i have the link (www.amity.edu/mauritius) itself stored in my database.

Comment: and the same value displaying in table td ? right ? what you get after hovering on this in status bar ? I mean whesite url ?

Comment: yes the same value is displaying. when hovering nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

if variable `$row['website']` has `http://` in start,It will redirect to `http://www.amity.edu/mauritius/` otherwise it will append local host url in start.

try this `:`

```
<?php
include ('db_connect.php');
$sql="select * from institution";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ins_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ins_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=" . addhttp($row['website']) . ">" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```